# VBScript doesn't go past the if statement

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a simple `VBScript` which gets the data from a database and iterate through them and generates a table. During this iteration, I want to capture some data (Values of a specific column) and save them in a variable for later use. But whenever my code reaches that `if` statement it doesn't loop anymore.

```
  Dim lats
  Dim longs
  Set lats = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
  Set longs = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
  %>
  <table>
    <tr><th>Office</th><th>Address</th><th>Comune</th><th>Province</th><th>Lat</th><th>Long</th><th>2G</th><th>3G</th><th>4G</th></tr>

    <%do until rs.EOF
        response.write("<tr>")
        for each x in rs.Fields
          response.write("<td>" & response.write(x.value) &"</td>")
          'IF the below statement equals true, the loop doesn't perform anymore
          If x.name = "SITE_LAT_N" Then
            lats.Add x.value
          ElseIf x.name = "SITE_LON_E" Then
            longs(indx) = x.value
          End If
          next
        rs.MoveNext
        response.write("</tr>")
      loop
      rs.close
      conn.close
      %>
    </table>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have `On Error Resume Next` in your code. Remove it and look at the error that gets displayed. Also, don't call `Response.Write` inside `Response.Write`.

Comment: No I don't have that On error resume next anywhere in my code. Also I fixed the Response.Write , Still the loop doesn't continue.

Answer (score 6):

```
longs(indx) = x.value
```

looks fishy. Evidence:

```
>> set al = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
>> al.Add "works"
>> WScript.echo al(0)
>> al(1) = "doesn't work"
>>
works
Error Number:       -2146233086
Error Description:  Der Index lag außerhalb des Bereichs. Er muss nicht negativ und kleiner als die Auflistung sein.
Parametername: index
```

In addition: Where does the `indx` come from? Can't you use

```
longs.add x.value
```

Comment: Fair assessment.